# Recibir parámetros de una solicitud AJAX en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy tratando de usar la FullCalendar, con MySQL como base de datos.

Al dar click en el calendario, levanta un modal con un formulario y, al dar click en un botón, quiero guardar los datos vía jQuery AJAX.
Pero no se están pasando los parámetros, solo inserta el campo por defecto `created_at`, pero los demás todos son `NULL`.

Este  es el código:

```
$('#btnOK').on('click',function(){
  var evento = $('#txtNombre').val();
  var ini = $('#txtIni').val();
  var fin = $('#txtFin').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/events/',
    data: {event : {evento: evento,ini: ini,fin: fin}},
    success: function(){
      console.log('Datos guardados');
    },
    error: function(){
      console.log('error ajax');
    }
  });

  console.log(evento+' '+ini+' '+fin);
});
```

Controller generado con scaffold:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  # GET /events
  # GET /events.json
  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  # GET /events/1
  # GET /events/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /events/new
  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  # GET /events/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /events
  # POST /events.json
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /events/1
  # PATCH/PUT /events/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update(event_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /events/1
  # DELETE /events/1.json
  def destroy
    @event.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Event was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:title, :start, :end)
    end
end
```

¿Alguna idea para arreglarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el javascript estás enviando:

```
data: {event : {evento: evento,ini: ini,fin: fin}}
```

sin embargo en el controlador tienes definido los parámetros distintos:

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:title, :start, :end)
end
```

No se cual de las dos definiciones sea la correcta, pero los parámetros deben tener el mismo nombre que la tabla `event` de tu base de datos.

Comment: la correcta es el controlador que tienes los mismos campos que la base de datos, es que  necesariamete tienen que llamarse igual?

Comment: En estricto rigor podrían llamarse distinto, pero Rails funciona bajo el paradigma de "convención sobre configuración", eso quiere decir que para tener que codificar menos, te tienes que adecuar a las convenciones ya definidas por Rails, entre ellas enviar los parámetros tal cual están definidos en tus strong parameters y en tu tabla de la bd. En caso contrario tendrías que programar la lógica, lo cual conllevaría más desarrollo que por defecto no era necesario.